# Syntax error in ~/.bashrc if statement

Tags: bashrc, syntax

In my terminal, it says that my `.bashrc` file possess a syntax error. I could identify this bit of lines from my `.bashrc` that were incorrect but cannot fix it.

This is the part of my `.bashrc` that appears to contain the problem:

```bash
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc
   if ! shopt -oq posix; then
   if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
     . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

Or as it appears in the editor:

[image: picture of the problematic part of my ~/.bashrc]

Comment: Couple of things: 1) repost the relevant part of your .bashrc into your question as text, not as an image; 2) post the exact error message you're receiving (add to your question).

Comment: I voted to close as "unclear what you are asking" because you haven't shared the full error message or enough of your `.bashrc` file to see where/what the error might be

Comment: the error message is bash: /home/fred/.bashrc: line 149: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: The relevant part in my .bashrc  is

Comment: if ! shopt -oq posix; then
      if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
     . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom see if "fi" is missing there,if it is not there add it.

Just put "fi" at the left margin at the last and close all the commands with "fi".

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FAng.png)

Comment: Hi, I added the 'fi' at the left margin but did not change nothing. is is important the indentation in the line or not ?

Comment: I have given the image did you refer that

Comment: hi indeed it was a missing 'fi'. it works now thanks